# C++: assembly code contains assert results

Tags: c++, assembly, assert, compiler-optimization

Here's the code:

```
#include <cassert>

int main() {
    assert(true==false); // A
    assert(true==true);  // B
}
```

Here's the assembly code ([link](https://godbolt.org/g/zaupj8)):

```
.LC0:
.string "/tmp/compiler-explorer-compiler11778-61-1sgmkbd.5d1m6g8pvi/example.cpp"
.LC1:
  .string "true==false"
main:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  mov ecx, OFFSET FLAT:main::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
  mov edx, 5
  mov esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
  call __assert_fail
main::__PRETTY_FUNCTION__:
  .string "int main()"
```

Line `A`, which should trigger an assertion failure, is reflected in the assembly code, but `B` is not.

My question is: now that the macro `assert()` is meant for runtime assertion, how can the compiler know the results and write it to the assembly?

Compiler: gcc 7.1, Optimization `-O0` (i.e. no optimization). I thought it is because of optimization, so I deliberately switched it off (did I?) by this option.

**Edit**: now that assert() can be evaluated at compile time, it seems to overlap with static_assert()..

Comment: "_is meant for runtime assertion, how can the compiler know the results and write it to the assembly_" Because the assertions you wrote - are compile-time constants, and could not, possibly, change during the run-time.

Comment: Also, assertions are meant to magically disappear.

Comment: It's pretty easy for the compiler to prove that "A" will always be hit, so there's no point in emitting code for "B".

Comment: @user1095108 -- it's not magic, it's just the preprocessor. But in this case it's neither: it's compiler optimization.

Comment: This is such a simple optimization that it's done even with `-O0`.

Comment: @user1095108 could you please clarify?

Comment: @JesperJuhl So the compiler runs the code 'x == y' during compile time, treating it as a constant expression. Am I correct?

Comment: @user8385554 The compiler does not "run it" (be careful with terms and semantics). But it does parse and interpret it and analyze it. And yes, based on that interpretation and analysis it can conclude that some of the code will *never* execute, so it can obviously omit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you’re using GCC and the GNU C library, so assuming `NDEBUG` is not defined, the `assert` macro is probably defined something like this:

```
# define assert(expr)                                                   \
  ((expr)                                                               \
   ? __ASSERT_VOID_CAST (0)                                             \
   : __assert_fail (__STRING(expr), __FILE__, __LINE__, __ASSERT_FUNCTION))
```

(copied from my `/usr/include/assert.h`)

Substituting this (and all the macros it depends on)* gets you something like

```
int main() {

  ((true == false)
       ? static_cast<void>(0)
       : __assert_fail("true==false", "assert.cpp", 4, "int main()"));

  ((true == true)
       ? static_cast<void>(0)
       : __assert_fail("true==true", "assert.cpp", 5, "int main()"));
}
```

Even at `-O0`, the compiler is smart enough to see that `true == true` and not `true == false`, so it knows it will call the first `__assert_fail` but it will never call the second. Since it will never call that second function, it won’t need the string `"true == true"` and doesn’t bother including it.

If you had made harder conditions, it wouldn’t have known which ones it would need, so it would have included everything.

EDIT to add: Even if you added another line with a more complicated condition, it wouldn’t necessarily add that either. For example, [here](https://godbolt.org/g/Gq5Aih) I’ve modified your code to add a check which must happen at runtime:

```
#include <cassert>

bool check_collatz_conjecture();

int main() {
    // assert(check_collatz_conjecture());
    assert(true==false);
    assert(true==true);
    assert(check_collatz_conjecture());
}
```

Because the compiler knows that the first assertion will be hit, and because `__assert_fail` is declared with `__attribute__((__noreturn__))`, the compiler knows it doesn’t need to worry about the rest of the function and it doesn’t include a `"check_collatz_conjecture()"` string. If you uncomment out the first assert it will include both that and `"true == false"`, though, because it doesn’t know if the Collatz conjecture is true (which, to be fair, no mathematician currently does).

* I got this by running `g++ -E assert.cpp -o assert.ii` to get the preprocessed code, then running `cat assert.ii | sed '/^#/d'` to remove the markers of file name and line number and to reformat the code into something more readable, and then manually replacing the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`s  with `"int main()"`s. If you’re confused about why the compiler is doing something, looking at the preprocessed output like this might help.

Comment: So it seems that the difference between assert() and static_assert() is that the latter **must** be evaluated at compile time, while assert() **could** be evaluated at compile time but also could be at runtime, right?

Comment: @user8385554 The compiler is allowed to evaluate anything it wants at compile time if it can. It can’t do this for user input, properly-seeded random numbers, etc., but only because it doesn’t know enough; it would be allowed to handle those at compile time as well if that were possible.